# Status of Task getting stuck at "WaitingForActivation"

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

This is in regard with .NET 4.0

I am trying to fetch data from multiple WebAPIs asynchronously using Task. In console application, the program is working just fine but when I am creating a web application, the status of Task is always getting stuck at "WaitingForActivation". Any help would be highly appreciated. The following is my piece of code:

```
    public String[] CallClientAPI(string[] addresses)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        int timeToWait = 3000; //wait for 3 seconds to fetch API Data

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(timeToWait);
            cts.Cancel();
        });

        Task<String[]> webTask = GetAPIData(addresses, cts.Token);
        //webTask is always in "WaitingForActivation" mode only ..

        if (!webTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            Thread.SpinWait(5000000);
        }

        String[] results = null;

        try
        {
            results = webTask.Result;
        }
        catch
        {               
        }
        //other code
    }
```

Edit:

--------------------Code for GetAPIData--------------------

```
    public Task<string[]> GetAPIData(String[] urls, CancellationToken token)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<string[]> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string[]>();
        WebClient[] webClients = new WebClient[urls.Length];

        token.Register(() =>
            {
                foreach (var wc in webClients)
                {
                    if (wc != null)
                        wc.CancelAsync();
                }                    
            });

        object m_lock = new object();
        int count = 0;
        List<string> results = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < urls.Length; i++)
        {
            webClients[i] = new WebClient();

            webClients[i].DownloadStringCompleted += (obj, args) =>
                {
                    if (args.Cancelled == true)
                    {
                        tcs.TrySetCanceled();
                        return;
                    }
                    else if (args.Error != null)
                    {
                        tcs.TrySetException(args.Error);
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        results.Add(args.Result);
                    }

                    lock (m_lock)
                    {
                        count++;
                        if (count == urls.Length)
                        {
                            tcs.TrySetResult(results.ToArray());
                        }
                    }
                };

            Uri address = null;
            try
            {
                address = new Uri(urls[i]);
                webClients[i].DownloadStringAsync(address, address);
            }

            catch (UriFormatException ex)
            {
                tcs.TrySetException(ex);
                return tcs.Task;
            }
        }

        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Comment: OMG `Thread.SpinWait(5000000);` ? Are you sure about what you're doing?

Comment: That was just a copy-paste .. I also tried with this line commented out. But the same "WaitingForActivation" prevailed :(

Comment: and the code for `GetAPIData` ?

Comment: Looks fine for me, Task status should change eventually when `DownloadStringCompleted` fires and all task completed.

Comment: But it doesn't .. maybe I might be missing something .. This works fine in a console application though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what is working just as desired. Plain and simple!!

```
    public String[] CallClientAPI(string[] addresses)
    {
        int timeToWait = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["API_QUERY_TIMEOUT"].ToString());
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(timeToWait);
                cts.Cancel();
            });

        ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
        po.CancellationToken = cts.Token;

        try
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(addresses, po, (address) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
                        request.Method = "GET";
                        request.ContentType = "text/xml";
                        request.Timeout = timeToWait;

                        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

                        Stream respstream = response.GetResponseStream();
                        Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
                        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(respstream, encode);

                        myresult.Add(sr.ReadToEnd());
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                });
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        return myresult.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're starting the downloads on the UI thread. The problem with that is that the `Completed` handlers are trying to execute back on the UI thread. But that's not possible, because the UI thread is blocked on the call to `Result`. The result is that you have a deadlock.

The proper solution to this is *not to block the UI thread*. This works especially well in C# 5.0 (which you can use with .Net 4.0, assuming you're using VS 2012), but it's also possible in C# 4.0 using things like `ContinueWith()`.

If you really want to block the UI thread while the downloads are being processed (I really don't recommend that), then execute all your `WebClient` code on a separate thread (using `Task.Factory.StartNew()`). That way, the `Completed` handlers won't try to resume on the UI thread, solving the deadlock.

Comment: Thanks! Upon further research, I found the same over here: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

For solving it, I used a Parallel.Foreach loop with a cancellation token and in the action method, I fired the requests normally. And like magic it worked!